# Unable to display records in dropdownList control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

I am using VB.Net 2010, and when I run the following code, I get **System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor**  displaying in the dropdownlist box

```
 cmbProdType.DataSource = ds
 cmbProdType.DisplayMember = "ProductType"
 cmbProdType.ValueMember = "ProductCode"
```

When I hover over the datasource, I can see the correct records. But its not displaying in the dropdownlist control.

Comment: Can you show the code populating ds?

Comment: The code that populates the ds is a dynamic sql query that is built on the fly. But as I mentioned, when I hover over the ds in the code above, I can see the correct records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmbProdType.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I don't usually bind to a dataset, I bind to the datatable in the dataset, but it looks like you have that working?

Second I set the datasource after I tell it the display and value members.

EDIT:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable("dt")
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductType")
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductCode")

    For i = 0 To 10
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        dr.Item("ProductType") = ChrW(i + AscW("A"))
        dr.Item("ProductCode") = i
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next


    cbo.DisplayMember = "ProductType"
    cbo.ValueMember = "ProductCode"


    cbo.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: That was my first guess also.

Comment: dwidel, can you post a sample code ? Just curious what your version would look like.